# How can I recreate this iOS font that has a shadow?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uifont

In the iOS clock app, the font in the table view cells has a slight shadow to it which gives the effect that the text is engraved....

[image]

How can I recreate that font with the engraved look?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Simply set the shadow color to white:

```
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `label.shadowColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];`?

Comment: Actually, no. This is UILabel's shadowColor property, not a CALayer's shadowColor property, and it's a UIColor.